# Comparing list with dictionary to make new list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have one list and one dictionary. I want to compare the list values with the keys of the dictionary. If I have:

```
mydict = {'Hello':1,'Hi':2,'Hey':3}
```

and:

```
mylist = ['Hey','What\'s up','Hello']
```

I want the output to be:

```
output = [3, None, 1]
```

Thanks!

I tried `[mydict[i] for i in mylist]` and I get an error instead of None. I then tried using nested for loops (I deleted that bit) but I decided that was to inefficient.

Comment: What have you tried? At this site, you need to show us your attempted code and say just why your code does not work well enough for your needs.

Comment: I tried `[mydict[i] for i in mylist]` and I get an error instead of `None`. I then tried using nested for loops (I deleted that bit) but I decided that was to inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
output = [ mydict.get(key) for key in mylist ]
```

Note that [dict.get](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) returns `None` if the key is not in the dict.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dict.get()`, which defaults to `None` if key does not exist:

```
[mydict.get(k) for k in mylist]
```

---

```
>>> mydict = {'Hello':1,'Hi':2,'Hey':3}
>>> mylist = ['Hey','What\'s up','Hello']
>>> out = [mydict.get(k) for k in mylist]
>>> out
[3, None, 1]
```